# How can I allow access to the web interface of a 3COM Superstack 4500 from a different network?

Tags: networking, router

I trying to access the web interface of a 3COM Superstack 4500 from a foreign network. By default this is blocked. I do have access via Telnet or Web from the inner network so I only need to know the commands to open the web interface to another network.

Any ideas? I already had a look at the manual and guides of 3COM but had no luck.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that product, but it looks industrial-grade enough for this question to belong on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the SuperStack has a `default route` or `gateway` set up to route out through to the foreign network.